# From $A$, Find $B+C\ =\ A\ $such that $BC=CB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

> **Let $A,\ B,\ C$ as square  matrices. Is there a general formula for finding $B,C\ $ such that: $A=B+C$ where $BC=CB$**

I am trying to extend to a particular case of matrix exponentials.

Example:

Find the matrix exponential $e^{At}$ where
$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&a\\0&1\\\end{matrix}\right)$

Since $A=I+\left(\begin{matrix}0&a\\0&0\\\end{matrix}\right)$

And there is a formula where $e^Be^C=e^{B+C}$ if $BC=CB$

Then $$e^{At}=e^{Bt+Ct}={(e}^{Bt})(e^{Ct})$$ such that $B=I$ and $C=\left(\begin{matrix}0&a\\0&0\\\end{matrix}\right)$

Now
$$e^{Bt}=\left(\begin{matrix}e^t&0\\0&e^t\\\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$e^{Ct}=e^{0t}(I+Ct+\frac{C^2t^2}{2}\ldots)$$

Since $C$ has only one (multiple) eigenvalues of 0, a special application of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that ${(C-0I)}^2=0$ (nilpotent)

Then $$e^{Ct}=e^{0t}(I+Ct)$$

Finally
$$e^{At}=\left(\begin{matrix}e^t&0\\0&e^t\\\end{matrix}\right)(I+\left(\begin{matrix}0&at\\0&0\\\end{matrix}\right))$$

---

This method only works for the case $BC=CB=IC=CI$
That’s why I am asking if for a general method of extracting $B,C$ which commutes.

Comment: Jordan-Chavalley decomposition.

Comment: in your example $C$ is not invertible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea: first upper-triangularize $A$ (namely $A'$). Then, as $A$ is invertible, all entries of the diagonal of $A'$ are non-zero so we can choose some $k\neq 0$ such that $A'=(A'-kI)+kI$ and $B':=A'-kI$ is still invertible. Therefore $B'$ and $C':=kI$ commute and $A'=B'+C'$.

Finally, as $A=D^{-1}A'D$ for some invertible $D$ then setting $B:=D^{-1}B'D$ and $C:=D^{-1}C'D$ you finally find that

$$
A=D^{-1}A'D=D^{-1}(B'+C')D=B+C\\
BC=D^{-1}B'C'D=D^{-1}C'B'D=D^{-1}C'D D^{-1}B'D=CB
$$
∎

P.S.: to upper-triangularize $A$ maybe you will need to use complex-valued matrices.